# When does Android system launches the intent in startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I want to know when exactly does the new activity gets launched (or when is the intent really sent by system). I created 2 activities for this purpose.
On Activity1, I entered

```
Log.d("Test", "Activity 2 is about to be created");
startActivityForResult(getIntentForLaunchingActivity2(), 5);
Log.d("Test", "startActivityForResult for Activity2 has been called");
```

In Activity2's onCreate method I added the following debug statement.

```
Log.d("Test", "Started Activity 2");
```

I observed the following sequence of statements

```
Activity 2 is about to be created
startActivityForResult for Activity2 has been called
Started Activity 2
```

I want to know if there is any sequence. Is this sequence something Android system level detail or the API's contract? Pardon me if this is really trivial. I have just started in the Android world and wanted to gain more accurate information. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: this is because it is an async call,  if it was sync one you would not need onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

To know how the activity communicates with each other you need to first learn the life cycle of an activity. please look at the link below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

After that you can see the delegate sequence mentioned below:

On Activity Created : Activity1

On Activity Started : Activity1

On Activity Resumed : Activity1

On Activity Paused  :  Activity1

On Activity Created : Activity2

On Activity Started : Activity2

On Activity Resumed : Activity2

On Activity SaveInstacneState : Activity1

On Activity Stopped : Activity1